# How to display only subcategory

Tags: plugins, categories

I have categories:

-Parent category
    --Subcategory
     ---Grandcategory

How i can display parent category and only subccategory(not display grandcategory).
My args:

```
$args = array(
                            'type'                     => 'product',
                            'child_of'                 => $category_ID,
                            'parent'                   => '',
                            'orderby'                  => 'name',
                            'order'                    => 'ASC',
                            'hide_empty'               => 0,
                            'hierarchical'             => 1,
                            'exclude'                  => '',
                            'include'                  => '',
                            'number'                   => '',
                            'taxonomy'                 => 'product_cat',
                            'pad_counts'               => true );
```

and i query :

```
$categories = get_categories( $args );
```

Comment: As an alternative you could switch from `get_categories()` to `wp_list_categories()` and use the `'depth'` parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) instead. It has `depth` parameter which will do exactly what you want (you can use custom walker class, if you need different output than default one).

Another way would be to write your own code (but it won't be a beautiful one). You can use something like this:

```
$args = ...
$categories = get_categories( $args );  // $category_ID as child_of
foreach ($categories as $k=>$category) {
    if ( $category->parent != $category_ID) {  // it's not direct child
        $parent_category = get_term($category->parent, 'product_cat');
        if ( $parent_category->parent != $category_ID ) {  // it's not grandchild either
            unset($categories[$k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove my answer since it went nowhere. Keep yours in my favorite.

Comment: yeahh. Thank you. I'm sorry but i cannot vote for you. Thank again.